# Why are multiple objects stored after each change in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

Take for example this:

```
$('select#submit_model').on('change', function(){

   model_object = {};
   console.log(model_object);

});
```

Why does the console log an extra object each time my select changes and the function fires?

For example, after first select it logs Object {}, after second select it logs Object {} Object {}, after third Object {} Object {} Object {} - and so on.

I am wondering this because I have conditional select inputs and data is filled in dependent on what a user selects, but after each "Change" function, an empty array is being added before my object (similar issue) - and then my function can breaks after further "on change events" because it is trying to read an object, but there are empty arrays in front of it (I can see logged to console).

Do I need to clean or clear my object somehow? Why does this happen?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: put `model_object = {};` outside of `on()` and add `var` to it

Comment: Is anything able to rerun the overall script, including the 1st line of the snippet (e.g. part a snippet of markup inserted with `.html()`)? The duplication may suggest that the `'change'` event handler is being bound multiple times, and it's called the same number of times for each occurrence of the event.

Comment: I think you are right - the problem is that this is all wrapped inside another onchange event which seems to be screwing with my example. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that you have some more code inside `on()` apart from the what you have shown.

You have to rectify your problem like below:-

```
var model_object = {};
$('select#submit_model').on('change', function(){

   //do your stuff with model_object

   console.log(model_object);

});
```

***Example:-***

```js
var model_object = {};
$('select#submit_model').on('change', function(){
   model_object['selected_value'] = $(this).val();
   console.log(model_object);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="submit_model">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
```

***Note:- In your code new instance (object) is creating every time when select-box values changed.***

Comment: Thank-you for your example, and you are right, in my code this is wrapped within another on change event (my mistake). Which seemed to be screwing things up. Thank-you for your answer and helping me to realise my error.

Comment: @Notorious  really glad to help you and thanks for your humble comment.:):)